# Using delegate to swap classes

Tags: jquery, css, razor, delegates

I am using jquery delegate function to toggle classes with no success , what i want is to toggle the class of

```
<li class="unselected-values">
```

to

```
<li class="<li class="unselected-values">
```

when the client clicks on the label, any ideas where i m getting it wrong , any suggestion or assistance will be appreciated. thnx

```
    <ul class="option-list swatch pockets">
                            @foreach (var pvaValue in attribute.Values)
                            {                                    
                                <li class="unselected-values">
                                    <input id="@(controlId)_@(pvaValue.Id)" type="checkbox" value="@pvaValue.Id" checked="@pvaValue.IsPreSelected" />
                                    <label for="@(controlId)_@(pvaValue.Id)" style="background-image:url(@(pvaValue.MenuIcon))">@pvaValue.Name</label>
                                </li>
                            }
                        </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
                      $(document).ready(function() {
                          $('.option-list swatch pockets').delegate('label', 'click', function(event) {
                              $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected-value');
                              console.log($(this).parent);
                              alert($(this).parent);
                              return false;

                          });


                      });
                                </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.option-list.swatch.pockets').delegate('label', 'click', function (event) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('unselected-values selected-value');
    console.log($(this).parent);
    alert($(this).parent);
    return false;
});
```

Your selector `$('.option-list swatch pockets')` was not correct. 
You needed to do like this `$('.option-list.swatch.pockets')` to get it correctly.

Comment: not really it has removed the class now , i want to switch classes , like if its click then selected value , then if its click again the class will swicth vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Your selector `$('.option-list swatch pockets')` is wrong, it means an element `pockets` which is inside a `swatch` element which is inside an element with class `option-list`.

Try

```
$('.option-list.swatch.pockets')
```

It means an element with classes `option-list`, `swatch` and `pockets`.

Also in order to toggle between two classes, you need to pass both classes to the [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.option-list.swatch.pockets').delegate('label', 'click', function(event) {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('unselected-values selected-value');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rE7g2/)

Comment: ur demo is working fine , dunno why in my case , the class is switching back to unselected-values

Comment: whether the element has the class `unselected-values` when the `li` is created

Comment: Also try more clicks to see the behaviour

Comment: if u click on side menu pocket and cuffs section under which pockets is define . by clicking on pocket the box with pockets comes up , that where i m trying to add class when pocket option is clicked